# handling timeout in wget

Tags: bash, timeout, wget

I have a bash script that checks if the **CHECKURL** variable has a response or not.
If the url is not valid or doesn't exist the script immediately exits and echo a message **"NOT VALID URL"**

I have one problem in which the url https://valid-url-sample.com is a valid url however my IP is rejected on the load balancer because it only respond on 443 request from specific IP's. The result is the script stays running until I it requires me to **control+c**.
I would like the script to handle this kind of condition and echoes **"VALID BUT NOT REACHABLE"**, I also added timeout on the wget command but still no luck. any thoughts on how to handle this?

**SCRIPT**

```
#!/bin/bash


TARGET=$1
CHECKURL=$(wget -S -t 1 --timeout=600 --spider https://${TARGET} --no-check-certificate 2>&1 | awk '/HTTP\// {print $2}')


if [[ ${CHECKURL} ]]; then
  echo "VALID URL"
else
  if [[ $? != 0 ]]; then
    echo "NOT A VALID URL"
  else
    echo "VALID BUT NOT REACHABLE"        
  fi
fi
```

**Sample script excution**

```
[root@ip-192-69-69-69 ~]# ./script.sh google.com
VALID URL
```

Comment: put an `exit` below the line `not reachable` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to use a log file like this:.

```
#!/bin/bash

TARGET="$1"

if wget -S -t 1 --timeout=600 --spider https://"${TARGET}" --no-check-certificate > log.txt 2>&1; then
    echo "VALID URL"
else
    error="$(awk 'BEGIN { IGNORECASE=1 } /( failed| error| bad|unable | invalid| unrecognized)/ { err=$0 } END { if(match(err,/http:\/\/: Invalid host name/)) err=""; printf("%s",err) }' log.txt)"
    # Connection reset by peer, Connection timed out, Network is unreachable.
    if printf '%s' "$error" | grep -qiE '( peer| timed| unreachable)'; then
        echo "VALID BUT UNREACHABLE"
    # ERROR 403: Access denied/Forbidden.
    elif printf '%s' "$error" | grep -q ' 403'; then
        echo "FORBIDDEN"
    # Not Found.
    elif printf '%s' "$error" | grep -q ' 404'; then
        echo "NOT FOUND"
    # Fatal error.
    else
         echo "FATAL ERROR"
         echo "$error"
    fi
    exit 1 # Exit the script
fi

# Delete the temporary log file.
# rm -f log.txt
```